# Hide page from history

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have run into a problem:
I have a page that will be processed many times a week by my customers and each time it will have a different identifier
example

```
compshop.php?Shopid=2252&sub=s

compshop.php?Shopid=2520&sub=se

compshop.php?Shopid=3152&sub=n

etc....
```

problem is if possible I don't want all of these to save to the persons history so every time they start typing my url these show as the primary result instead of my home page.
is there a way to stop this

I thought the cache meta tag would deal with this but it appears the cache tag is only for SE indexing

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can redirect all URLs with invalid (old) identifiers to the correct page or home page?

Comment: it does currently (if not an assigned identifier) send you to the login page - I was hoping there might be another solution though

Comment: location.replace(URL) will replace a page in history. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Sounds like you might want to reconsider your URL scheme.  How is the data populated in the URL currently (i.e. what triggers the "processing")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a randomly generated parameter, it's extremely unlikely any page will be visited more than once, but your page can still be accessed by URL alone.

For example,

```
compshop.php?Shopid=2252&sub=s&t=69396872

compshop.php?Shopid=2520&sub=se&t=17094891

compshop.php?Shopid=3152&sub=n&t=79125863
```

It's not hiding the pages from the history, but it is mostly ensuring that the page is only entered into the history once, so your homepage should still show up first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're about out of luck unless you can send the parameters over POST instead of GET. As @PWHite just mentioned you could append a random value to the parameters as well to make sure that even the same Shopid/sub would show as "different" pages in the history, thus putting your home page at the top of the list in terms of # of visits.